# Rename Django's auth_user table?

Tags: django, django-models

Stupid question time.  In Django, if you want to specify the name of a model's table, you'll do this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mymodel'
```

Is it possible to change the name of Django's default auth_user table in a similar fashion?  I'm always running manual queries against the user table and it would be much faster to type 'user' than 'auth_user'. I've looked at the Django docs and done some Internet searches and I haven't seen anyone address this question.

Thanks!

Comment: It _should_ be possible by subclassing `User` with your custom class then using it as a custom user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Yes, except you should subclass AbstractUser, not User.

Comment: Why not? The poster wants all the functionality that the `User` has, only change the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) and [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) have given you good answers. You can extend either one of the classes User or AbstractUser, with the small difference that for the latter you will also need to add the *swappable* attribute in you Meta class.

Here is an example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser # (or simply User)

class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'  # ONLY for AbstractUser
        db_table = 'user'
```

**However, pay attention to using 'user' as a table name, because there are databases where this is a reserved word !!!**

Good luck.